# Getting an array of user meta information from a custom field in wordpress

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I want to show the custom field entrys from a custom field (advanced custom field relationship field) from a wordpress user page:

```
<?php if ( $themeta != array($user->name_of_custom_field) ) echo $user->name_of_custom_field; ?>
```

But this gives me only "Array" as a result.

EDIT:

Okay with this i get an array of IDs, but not the names of the fields:

```
<?php
    $values = $user->user_faecher;
    if (isset($values)) {

        foreach($values as $value) {
            if($value != end($values)){
                echo $value;
            } else {
                echo $value;
            }
        }

    }
?>
```

AND `var_dump($values);` gives me the field entrys, too, like:

```
325329array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "325" [1]=> string(3) "329" }
```

But how can i show the names instead of just the IDs?

Comment: Tried to do a `print_r($user);` and see what kind of data the `$user->name_of_custom_field;` contains?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you to delete the comment and remove all personal information (email), and then include the array in your question instead,

Comment: Thanks for the hint but the email doesn't even exist ... i mean ... "diana@ross ..." ;)

Comment: Hard to know, but in general never include personal information :)